# How I can wrap some <li> in something in <html> so I can put some in left and some in right?

Tags: html, list, css

I have a `ul li` like this

```
<ul class="right-p">
/// here is a lot of li
</ul>
```

I want to show all of them in left and last one in right so I put float right for last so everything goes fine.

Is there any way I can wrap all my left `li` in something so I can easily control them using CSS?

I mean, I can't put `Div > li` (it breaks the rule). Can `li` wrap inside anything that not broke any rule of HTML5 (yup).

How to wrap `li` inside `ul` without `div`? Is there any element that exists to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to format all the `li`'s differently to the last one, perhaps putting them in a *box*, then can the last `li` really be considered as part of the same list? Perhaps it should just be a separate element?

However, you could use the css `:last-child` selector to format the last item. If (just as an example) you put the `ul` in a box (visually) then you might use css-rules to move the last item below/outside of the box.

So, in css, you could apply rules to all of the `li`, using `.right-p li`, and follow this with the `:last-child` selector to overrule these settings for the last item.

Comment: Thank you for the edits @millimoose. On my next answer I will find these inline tags.

Comment: @andew I do it diffferent. Check my answer.